# Building machine learning model with variable targets and on the run

Tags: machine-learning, training

I want to add Machine learning predictive capabilities to an existing application; the data that will be used to train the model is stored in a database.

My problem is as follows:

in a typical machine learning project, you have a set of features that you use to train the model, and a single column, which is the target. In my case, most columns can be the target; for instance, the user can select "sales." in this case, the "sales" column would be the target, and it won't be used as a feature in training. On the other hand, if the user wants to predict the "Quantity", which is another column, then the "sales" column would be a feature used in training and so on, and once deployed, the user would need to provide the "sales" value to predict the quantity required to achieve this sales amount. How do I approach this, as I have more than 20 columns that can be either a feature or a target?

the machine learning model should be customized for each customer; due to data residency requirements, I won't have access to each user's data, so the training of the models shall be done in the customer's premises dynamically, is there any way to ensure the model's performance?

I thought about training a CAT boost model or any other model with reasonable defaults on the run, storing it somewhere and using it again whenever needed. However, I have no means of ensuring the model's performance. All that I need is some hints on how to approach this problem so that I can read more into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's at least two ways to approach these requirements.

Pick the 20 columns of greatest interest to customers for prediction.
Train, evaluate, and deploy 20 regression models.

In data science we learn the "shape" of business data.
Computing covariance can help with this.
We find that some combinations of feature values
will be routinely observed, while other combinations
are extremely rare.
Take advantage of this in order to serve your customers.
Choose a distance metric, and use a clustering technique
such as K-means to characterize your training data.
At inference time, given a feature vector of length 19,
use it to identify nearest cluster and to predict the target feature.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: I have sample data, but I am not sure if it will be representative of the customer’s original data since I don’t have access to it. Do you recommend deploying the models trained with the data I have, or should I train them locally to find the best parameters and then use those same parameters to train on the customer’s data using thier servers ?